# Pyplot colors not as expected

Tags: python, colors, matplotlib

Does anyone know why this code doesn't plot the boxes colors correctly. I want each component to be a different color but they all come out black with a blue legend.

```
from numpy import array, zeros
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Components: Useage times (start, stop), wattage, detail

COMPONENTS = {"fridge": ( [(0.0,24.0)], 35, " Litres"),
              "kettle": ([(7.3,7.33), (19.0,19.3)], 2500, ""),
              "netbook": ([(8.0,9.3),(12.0,15.0)], 12.5, ""),
              "light bulb": ([(18.0,22.0)], 20, "")
              }
COLORS = ('b','g','r','c','m','y','k','w')
PLOT = []
TIME = range(24*60)

Powers = [] # list of array of power for each component
for key in COMPONENTS.keys(): # each useage
    p = zeros(len(TIME))
    for j in COMPONENTS[key][0]: # start and stop
        start = round(j[0]*60)
        end = round(j[1]*60)
        p[start:end] = COMPONENTS[key][1]
    Powers.append(p)

b=zeros(len(TIME))
for i in range(len(COMPONENTS.keys())):
    PLOT.append(plt.bar(TIME,Powers[i],width = 1, color=COLORS[i], bottom=b))
    b+=Powers[i]


plt.ylabel('Power (W)')
plt.xlabel('Time (h)') ###
plt.title('Power Cycle')
plt.xticks(range(0,25*60,60) ,[str(t) for t in range(25)])
plt.legend( tuple([i for i in PLOT]), tuple([c for c in COMPONENTS.keys()]) )

plt.show()
```

Comment: What gave you the idea to use all caps variable names? This is hurting my eyes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code, as far as the graph is concerned, is fine. The problem is that there are too many bars, so you only see the black borders. This is what looks when zooming in:
[image]

To get the legend right, pass the `label` argument while plotting, then just call `plt.legend()` without arguments when you're done.